# PL/SQL issue concerning Frequent Itemset

Tags: oracle, plsql, bigdata, analysis

I'm trying to build a PL/SQL application to mine frequent item sets out of a set of given data and I've run into a bit of a snag.  My PL/SQL skills aren't as good as I'd like them to be, so perhaps one of you can help me understand this a bit better.

So to begin, I'm using the Oracle data mining procedure: *DBMS_FREQUENT_ITEMSET.FI_TRANSACTIONAL*

While reading the documentation, I came across the following example which I have manipulated to query over my data set:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE FI_VARCHAR_NT AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

CREATE TYPE fi_res AS OBJECT (
itemset      FI_VARCHAR_NT,
support      NUMBER,
length       NUMBER,
total_tranx  NUMBER
);
/

CREATE TYPE fi_coll AS TABLE OF fi_res;
/

create or replace 
PROCEDURE freq_itemset_test is
    cursor freqC is
          SELECT itemset
          FROM table(
            CAST(DBMS_FREQUENT_ITEMSET.FI_TRANSACTIONAL(CURSOR(SELECT sale.customerid, sale.productid FROM Sale INNER JOIN Customer ON customer.customerid = sale.customerid WHERE customer.region = 'Canada' )
                  ,0,2, 2, NULL, NULL) AS fi_coll));   
      coll_nt  FI_VARCHAR_NT;
    num_rows int;
    num_itms int;
  BEGIN
    num_rows := 0;
    num_itms := 0;
    OPEN freqC;
    LOOP
      FETCH freqC INTO coll_nt;
      EXIT WHEN freqC%NOTFOUND;
      num_rows := num_rows + 1;
      num_itms := num_itms + coll_nt.count;
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Rows: ' || num_rows || ' Columns: ' || num_itms);
  CLOSE freqC;
END;
```

My reasoning for using the Oracle FI_TRANSACTIONAL over straight SQL is that I will need to repeat this analysis for multiple dynamic values of K, so why reinvent the wheel?  Ultimately, my goal is to reference each individual item sets returned by the procedure and return the set with the highest support based on some query logic.  I will be incorporating this block of PL/SQL into another that basically changes the literal in the query from 'Canada' to multiple other regions based on the content of the data.

My question is: How can I actually get a programmatic reference on the data returned by the cursor (freqC)?  Obviously I do not need to count the rows and columns, but that was part of the example.  I'd like to print out the item sets with DBMS print line after I've found the most occurring item set.  When I view this in a debugger, I see that each fetch of the cursor actually returns an item set (in this case, k=2, so two items).  But how do I actually touch them programmatically?  I'd like to grab the sets themselves as well as fi_res.support.

As always, thanks to everyone for sharing their brilliance!

Comment: . . What do you mean by "a programmatic reference on the data returned by the cursor"?  Would inserting the data into a table with a sequenced identity column solve the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to reference the actual values returned by the freqC. Each iteration has an item set in "coll_nt," but I'm not certain how to programatically access it. If you look at the sample code above, one line uses the .count property to increment "num_itms."Is there something like this for me to actually access the data in coll_nt? My current understanding of this example is that I'd need to access a table of numbers within a table.  Inserting the data with a sequence won't help because the data already exists.The fi_transactional procedure mines the data properly, but I need to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fetching your data into a nested table.  So to see the data in there, you would need to loop over the nested table:

```
FOR i IN coll_nt.FIRST .. coll_nt.LAST
LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(i||': '||coll_nt(i));
END LOOP;
```

For much more information on nested tables and other types of collections, see the presentation at: 
http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/8253.everything-you-need-to-know-about-collections-but-were-afraid-to-ask.aspx